# How low does c have to be to be able to drop the constant from O(cn)?

Tags: big-o

Maybe this has a very simple answer, but: 
If we have O(2*n), this is considered O(n).

But if we have O( (n-1) * n), I'm pretty sure this is considered O (n^2).

For what values of this constant is this considered "droppable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "Any constant". But in your example `(n-1)` is not a constant, since it depends on `n`.

So the constant can be as big as you wish, as long as it does not depend on the input size.

Think about Big-Oh as a way to reduce a function to its basic asymptotics. This means you strip off all constant factors and lower order terms. But it still describes a function.

To make the example from your comment work: Let `f(n) = n/2` and `g(n) = 5`.
Then `f = O(n)` and `g = O(1)`. Big O tells you nothing about the relation of `f` and `g` for a specific value of `n`. But in case you know the function you can evaluate the functions for a specific value of `n`. This changes nothing about the asymptotics.

If this functions are coming from running times of algorithms such comparison can tell you for what size of input a bad algorithm works better than a good one. E.g. Mergesort runs in `O(n log n)`, Bubblesort in `O(n^2)`. Mergesort is much better than Bubblesort, but is also much more complex. So if you want to sort just 4 elements, you don't want to use Mergesort.

Comment: Oh okay! Well suppose n=10, and we had  O(5); if we phrase it O(n/2) vs O(5), then it would be O(n) in one case and O(1) in the other. (?)

Comment: I extended my answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 0):

n is not a constant. n is considered to be very large most of the time. A small n is not interesting in the big O context. So all in all any constant may be dropped.